# How can I tell if someone is using wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress

Can I tell by looking at the source code if someone is using wordpress?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. View source and look at the meta generator tag. You'll see something like this if they're using Wordpress:

```
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.0" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if it has this meta-tag as most Wordpress solutions have:

```
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.0.1" />
```

Or go to `/wp-admin/` on the domain to see if there is an adminstration login.